# Spring security UserDetails interace getPassword

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an Spring app that works as i want it to work however i bumped into a behaviour that i do not understand i.e. 
in order to mary my app with spring security i had  to extend my  UserRepositoryUserDetails class with my hibenrate User class and implement UserDetails. As mentioned all works well but i noticed that UserDetails interface has a method called  "String getPassword();" which is not imlpemented in my UserRepositoryUserDetails class but the application is still working. Then i implemented that method and noticed that i had to call explicetelly the super class getPassword  in order for that construct to wrok. The base User class also has a method  getPassword() as well as "getUsername()" but what i do not uderstand is why i need to to tell in the getPassword() to use explicetelly the method from the super class i.e. the "User" and i do not need to call the super keyword under the getUsername();

```
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {

        return super.getPassword();
    }
```

here are the classes in question.

```
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.syncServer.Model.acount.Users;


final class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends Users implements UserDetails{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4032653746283400246L;

    public UserRepositoryUserDetails (Users user) {
         super(user);
     }



    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {

        return super.getPassword();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return getEnabled();
    }



}
```

and the second class

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-binary")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class", value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy") })
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private UUID userId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @DuplicateUser
    private String userName;

    @UserPassword
    private String password;

    @UserPassword
    private String PasswordHashVersion;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled;

    @NotNull
    private String salt;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<Role> roles;

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<Quota> quota;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<UserAttribute> userAttribute;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Users user) {
        this.setUserId(user.userId);
        this.setUserName(user.userName);
        this.setPassword(user.password);
        this.setSalt(user.salt);
        this.setEnabled(user.enabled);
        this.setDescription(user.description);

    }

    public Users(@DuplicateUser @Name String userName,
            @UserPassword String password, Boolean enabled, String description) {

        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.salt = BCrypt.gensalt();
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.description = description;

    }

    public Users(@DuplicateUser @Name String userName,
            @UserPassword String password, String description, Role role,
            Quota quota) {

        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles.add(role);
        this.quota.add(quota);
        this.description = description;
    }

    public UUID getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(UUID userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    public void setSalt(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Collection<Quota> getQuota() {
        return quota;
    }

    public void setQuota(Collection<Quota> quota) {
        this.quota = quota;
    }

    public Collection<UserAttribute> getUserAttribute() {
        return userAttribute;
    }

    public void setUserAttribute(Collection<UserAttribute> userAttribute) {
        this.userAttribute = userAttribute;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Addition 1:

i removed completely the @Override getPassword  method and  started debuggin and put the breakpoint under getUserName(). The abstract class AbstractAuthenticationToken  has method called getName which calles trough proxy (UserDetails) the getUserName from my base hibernate entity class, so the getUsername is called. One more strange thing is that my class UserRepositoryUserDetails  implements UserDetails and now i do not have any implementation of getPassword() but eclipse is find with it. I am lost :( , In my java lessons i have learned that if a class implements interface it has to implement all of the interface method signatures right?

Comment: It seems unlikely that `getUsername` is called at all, since it wouldn't return. I would debug through your authentication code and see what's happening in more detail. If you are using a custom `AuthenticationProvider` it may never actually be called.

Comment: I started debugging as you proposed and came across 
AbstractAuthenticationToken  then i saw your name in the authors name :). I added my finding, please see Addition 1  of my question

Comment: `getUsername` and `getUserName` are different methods. Note the case.

Comment: ok so i changed getUserName to getUsename all over my project and then i saw that i need the keyword super in getUsername as well, thus my explanation to this is that when i had "@Override public String getUsername"  it was calling the object that  the interface  "UserDetails" defined however since UserRepositoryUserDetails was extending Users" and there was no ambiguity between "getUsername" and get "getUserName" is was able to call the correct method from the parent class.

Comment: The last thing that i need to clear is why eclipse if fine with the construct when UserRepositoryUserDetails has no getPassword() method implemented as the interface "UserDetails" imply.

Comment: holmis83 thank you for your responce

Comment: @Tito Sorry, my mistake. I didn't notice the case difference. However that is a bit confusing and probably best avoided if you can.

Comment: @Luke Taylor it was my mistake not yours. Thank you for your help .